# Installed Cygwin64 and cannot find unresolved inclusion in <iostream> when in eclipse

Tags: c++, cygwin, iostream

I linked to as many of the libraries as I can find and still I get an unresolved inclusion for `<iostream>` in eclipse. I even searched the c:\cygwin\ directory for iostream and I cannot find it. So, how do I find this basic library in the cygwin64 installation?

Answer (score 1):

The default installation for Cygwin is quite minimal. In particular, it doesn't include software development tools.

Re-run the Cygwin `setup.exe` program and add `gcc-g++` to your system. (It is in the Devel category on the Select Packages screen.) This will add the C++ compiler and Standard C++ library.